# Protocol functions in separate files

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Am trying to organize my project, and I was wondering if what am about to explain is possible: let's say I have a protocol that have the definitions of 10 functions, some of them is used to transfer data between view controllers (delegate).

Now, when I make a view controller conform to that protocol I need to define all of those functions, witch makes my view controller loaded with code. What I was wondering is , if it's possible to make a separate class for example Service, then make that class conform to that protocol and in my view controller I would just call Service.nameOfFunction().

I don't know how this would work with delegate, for example if there a function that uses MapView, I'll need to put it as a parameter, but in the other viewcontroller I don't have a MapView so what will I put in parameters when calling the function?

I know it's a bit confusing, but I hope you understand.

Comment: Swift protocols allow default implementation/extensions. You can provide common actions of each method in your protocol in protocols default extension itself. But the con with this approach is you wont be able to exploit the benefits of inheritance. Second solution would be make a parent ViewController lets say BaseViewController and make it to confirm the protocol and provide default implementation for each method in protocol there and make all other VCs in your project extend from BaseViewController and override the methods if customization needed in each child VC

Comment: but the second approach won't work with delegates

Comment: Unfortunately in swift4 child view controllers can no longer override methods in parent's extension, that means that you can not override the protocol methods implementation of parent, one work around I always use is, I never write the code directly in protocol method rather I declare a function put all code in there and call that method from method in protocol, that way you still have the flexibility to override parent view controllers protocol implementation :D

Comment: where would you declare that function?

Comment: In parent view controller itself. For example, if you have a method which says get VC name in protocol, in BaseViewController's extension rather than saying `func getVCName() -> String { return "abcd" }` I will declare a function in BaseViewController say `func VCName() -> String { return "abcd" }` and simply call `func getVCName() -> String { self. VCName() }` that way when ChildVC needs to provide its customized code it can simply override `VCName`

Comment: oh I see thank you.

Comment: Another catch, if you dont want all these multiple method declaration for each method in protocol, you can declare your protocols as `@objc` or `NSObjectProtocol`. You can not override only swift protocol method in ParentViewController extension but Objective-C protocol methods you can still override as usual :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set a default value for the parameter in method declaration.
While calling the function, u can either pass a value or skip it. If a value is passed then that will be overridden inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

You will make optional functions in swift protocol e.g
`

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol {

    @objc optional func doSomething()

}

class MyClass: MyProtocol {

    // no error

}`
```

No need to confirm optional methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol SomeProtocol { 
  func someProtocolMethod()
}

extension SomeProtocol {
  func someProtocolMethod() {
    // Default impl here (also can leave empty) (*)
  }
}

class SomeClass: SomeProtocol {
  // Currently have default implementation of someProtocolMethod -> (*)
}
```